# Объединить два массива, только совпадающие элементы

Tags: java, массивы

```
long[] a = new long[]{45017,96741,11751,23772,58825};
long[] b = new long[]{23772,88781,23777};
```

Как 2 массива объединить в один, чтобы в новом (третьем) массиве были только совпадающие элементы, в данном случае `23772` ?

Comment: а вам с какой сложностью решение надо? В лоб за O(nm) поумнее за O(n log m) или за O(n+m)?

Comment: @pavel интересно про О(n+m). Можно ссылку, где почитать? Спасибо

Comment: для получения O(n+m) есть смысл воспользоваться multiset или map, теми которые hash. Алгоритм - ложим в hash multiset весь массив а, потом идём по массиву b, если элемент есть в сете, то удаляем его и ложим в массив - ответ.

Comment: @pavel - а поиск по hash multiset за константное время? О_о... вот я раньше мучился(

Comment: можно конкретные примеры?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский да, multiset "под капотом" это обычный map<Type, Integer>. А вообще, если сильно надо, то хеш-таблица с простым связыванием минут за 10 пишется.

    #define SIZE 10
#define MOD 1000007

long long Hash[MOD][SIZE];

void InsertX(long long X){
 int H = X%MOD;
 Hash[H][ ++Hash[H][0] ] = X;  
}

bool Find(long long X){
    int H = X%MOD;
    for (int j=1;j<=Hash[H][0];j++)
      if (Hash[H][j] == X)
         return true; 
    return false;
}

Comment: А порядок элементов в результирующем массиве вам важен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
private static List<Long> asList(long[] array) {
    List<Long> res = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
    for (long l : array) {
        res.add(l);
    }
    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] a = new long[]{45017,96741,11751,23772,58825};
    long[] b = new long[]{23772,88781,23777};
    List<Long> cList = asList(a);
    cList.retainAll(asList(b));

    System.out.println(cList);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

На Java-8:

```
long[] result = LongStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).distinct().toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение с временной сложностью `O(m + n)`:

```
private static Long[] getIntersection (long[] a, long[] b) {
    HashSet<Long> aSet = new HashSet<>(),
        bSet = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        aSet.add(a[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        bSet.add(b[i]);
    }
    ArrayList<Long> intersection = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Long l : aSet) {
        if(bSet.contains(l)) {
            intersection.add(l);
        }
    }
    return intersection.toArray(new Long[]{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В верхнем цикле пробегайтесь по элементам 1-го массива
2. Во внутреннем цикле сравнивайте элемент 1-го массива со всеми элементами второго до тех пор пока не будет совпадения.
3. При совпадении помещайте совпавший элемент в список.
4. Список преобразуйте в массив.

Comment: Немного не точно сформулировал вопрос, а если неизвестное количество входных массивов, как получить?

Comment: Добавьте ещё один вложенный цикл, который будет все массивы перебирать. Если надо при этом, чтобы искомое значение присутствовало во всех массивах, то просто завершайте цикл при ненахождении значения первого массива в любом из остальных.